# generics and inheritance question

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have three classes:

```
public abstract class fileHandler<Key extends Object, Value extends Object> {
}    

public A extends fileHandler<String, String[]> {
}

public B extends fileHandler<String, String> {
}
```

Now in my main function i do something like this:

```
fileHandler file= null;
If (<condition>) {
    fileHandler = new A();
} else
    fileHandler = new B():
}
```

But this gives 2 compile time errors:

1. Cannot convert A to fileHandler
2. Cannot convert B to fileHandler

How can I get rid of these errors as I don't get this error if base class is not generic.

#### Update:

My class hierarchy is:

1. `class fileHandler<Key, Value> {     }`
2. `class A extends fileHandler<String, String[]> {     }`
3. `class B extends fileHandler<String, String> {     }`
4. class C that calls function `gen(object of A)` or
5. class D that calls function `gen(object of B)`.
6. both C and D are derived from abstract class E.

Now how should I define these functions in C and D and E:

I gave the following:

#### E:

```
public abstract void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

#### C:

```
void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

#### D:

```
void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

C, D, and E give error fileHandler is raw type. Reference to generic type fileHandler(Key, Value) should be parameterized.

Comment: may I ask, what `extends Object` is useful for?

Comment: If you don't capitalize your class name, it is not Java.

Comment: yes but i got formatting all wrong in that question

Comment: @user unknown - removed Object

Comment: @irreputable - in my code, i have it capialied, here i wrote it by mistake :)

Comment: This is complaining (giving a warning, which sounds like an Eclipse-ism) because FileHandler is a parametrized class. To clean them up modify the abstract Gen method (and its concrete implementations) to be parametrized (i.e public abstract <KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE> void gen(FileHandler<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE> A);)

Comment: What exactly did you not understand in "reference to ... should be parameterized" ?

Comment: Edit the original question instead of cluttering the site with duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a generic type with different type arguments, the two instantiations are not type compatible.  Different instantiations of a generic type are not type-equivalent in the way that a class that inherits from another class is type-equivalent to that class, even when the type arguments themselves may be related by inheritance.  Genericity and polymorphism are two separate language features.

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
// Java defaults unspecified type arguments to Object.
fileHandler<Object, Object> file;

if (...) {
   // Error: fileHandler<String, String> is not equivalent to fileHandler<Object, Object>
   file = new fileHandler<String, String>();
} else {
   // Error: fileHandler<String, String[]> is not equivalent to fileHandler<Object, Object>
   file = new fileHandler<String, String[]>();
}
```

If you truly want to isolate a polymorphic interface that is independent of the types used to instantiate your fileHandler class, then I would suggest you use an interface:

```
interface IFileHandler
{
    // If this interface needs to talk about keys and values, it
    // does so using only java.lang.Object.
}

public class fileHandler<Key extends Object, Value extends Object>
    implements IFileHandler
{
    // ...
}

public class A extends fileHandler<String, String>
{
    // ...
}

public class B extends fileHandler<String, String[]>
{
    // ...
}

IFileHandler file;

if (...) {
    file = new A();
} else {
    file = new B();
}
```

Comment: what would interface contain in this case ?

Comment: This was very helpful. I re-wrote using interface and everything worked perfect !!

Comment: @user###: Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to assign an instance to the class name. You should instead be saying

```
if (condition) {
   file = new A();    
} else {
   file = new B();
}
```

"file" is the reference here "fileHandler" is the class name.

Cheers.

Comment: The same still holds. Also as an aside Java classes are usually named using StudlyCaps (i.e. FileHandler)

Answer (score 1):

I get no compile error... if I fix all the error in your provided code

```
  class fileHandler<Key, Value> {
    }

  class A extends fileHandler<String, String[]> {
    }

  class B extends fileHandler<String, String> {
    }
```

then

```
fileHandler file= null;
if (/* condition */) 
{
    file = new A();
} 
else
{
    file = new B();
}
```

Comment: please cooment on my latest query on this bug at the end

Answer (score 0):

How you decide to fix this warning really depends on what you are trying to do and how strictly you want to restrict the allowed types for the parameter of `gen()`.

**Example 1**

Very loose

```
abstract class E {
    public abstract void gen(fileHandler<?,?> A) throws Exception;
}

class C extends E {
    @Override
    public void gen(fileHandler<?,?> A) throws Exception {}
}
```

**Example 2**

Restrict `Key` generic to be a `String`

```
abstract class E {
    public abstract void gen(fileHandler<String,?> A) throws Exception;
}

class C extends E {
    @Override
    public void gen(fileHandler<String,?> A) throws Exception {}
}
```

**Example 3**

You probably want to name the unrestricted type so you can refer to it.

```
abstract class E {
    public abstract <Value> void gen(fileHandler<String,Value> A) throws Exception;
}

class C extends E {
    @Override
    public <Value> void gen(fileHandler<String,Value> A) throws Exception {}
}
```