# generics and inheritance question

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generics and inheritance question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438753/generics-and-inheritance-question)

Hi,
I have follwing theree classes:

```
public abstract class fileHandler <Key extends Object, Value extends Object> {

}

public A extends fileHandler<String, String[]> {

}

public B extends fileHandler<String, String> {

}
```

Now in my main function i do something like this:

```
fileHandler file= null;

If (<some condition>) {

    file = new A();

} else

    file = new B():
}
```

But this gives 2 compile time errors:

- Cannot convert A to
  fileHandler
- Cannot convert B to
  fileHandler

How can I get rid of these errors as I don't get this error if base class is not generic.

Thanks a lot in advance,
-JJ