# function calls using objects of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generics and inheritance question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438753/generics-and-inheritance-question)

my class hierarchy is:

1. `class fileHandler<Key, Value> {     }`
2. `class A extends fileHandler<String, String[]> {     }`
3. `class B extends fileHandler<String, String> {     }`
4. class C that calls function `gen(object of A)` or
5. class D that calls function `gen(object of B)`.
6. both C and D are derived from abstract class E.

Now how should I define these functions in C and D and E:

i gave follwoing:

E:

```
public abstract void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

C:

```
void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

D:

```
void gen (fileHandler A) throws exception;
```

E: gives error fileHandler is raw type. Reference to generic type fileHandler(Key, Value) should be parameterized.

C and D also give same error.